# how to Run two BlackBerry simulators in windows eclipse?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

How to Run two instance of BlackBerry simulator in windows eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation regarding developing with BlackBerry Messenger indicates that [you can run two simulators at once](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/25813/Installl_the_BB_Sim_package_1360786_11.jsp), at least with the simulators that come bundled with the BBM SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.  If you try, you will get an error message saying only one simulator can run at a time.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is:

1. Install the blackberry eclipse plugins twice and make two
   workspace of each eclipse.
2. Run the two simulators in each eclipse and error like "could not
   open port 19780 and it is use by another program....." will pop
   out in one of your simulator.
3. So made the  changes in pin,
       data-port values in .bat files, rimpublic.property    files inside
       MDS and fledge-settings.conf in one of your    simulator... but this
       changes will not be reflected on your eclipse.
4. So what you need to do is, when you click the debug configuration from your
   eclipse, you will see the simulator option  there. So, click the simulator and change the PIN value, whatever    you have made the changes in .bat files.. and just after that in the simulator you will again find the option of network, there unselect the disable registration button...once all this changes is made click apply and restart your eclipse... this will surely solved your    problem